# Caching large files transparently over HTTP

Tags: http, cache, squid, varnish

I have a rather peculiar server set up to work with: I have files stored on an HTTP accessible server (Windows Azure Storage - about 800gb of content) but must serve them to people from a different server (with a small disk -- 40gb). Not wanting to double bandwidth costs, I'd like to have some sort caching.

Can squid be used as a forward proxy or will it block to download a full (e.g. 1GB file) before serving it to the client system? Alternatively, is Varnish any more viable for this?

Answer (score 2):

Answering for myself.
Varnish, [a while back](http://info.varnish-software.com/blog/http-streaming-varnish), added support for streaming over HTTP. This means that the Varnish server will, as it is downloading to cache, let clients download the file.